# Error deploying a cloud function ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) ResponseError: status=[403], code=[Forbidden]

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to implement the deployment of a cloud function from a repository in GitLab to Google Cloud functions via Gitlab CI/CD. I'm getting the error in the title and below.

ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) ResponseError: status=[403], code=[Forbidden], message=[Permission 'cloudfunctions.functions.get' denied on resource 'projects/ahinko-website-prd/locations/us-central1/functions/send_contact' (or resource may not exist).]

My .gitlab-CI.yml file is:

```
image: google/cloud-sdk:slim

stages: 
  - release 
  - function_deploy 
 
before_script:
  - gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file $GOOGLE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE
  - gcloud config set project $GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID

release:
  stage: release
  script:
    - gsutil -m rm gs://ahinko.com/**
    - gsutil -m cp -R src/client-side/* gs://ahinko.com
  environment:
    name: production
    url: https://ahinko.com
  only: 
    - master

function_deploy: 
  stage: function_deploy
  script:
    - gcloud functions deploy send_contact --entry-point=send_contact_form --ingress-settings=all --runtime=python37 --trigger-http
  environment: 
    name: production
    url: https://ahinko.com
  only:
    - ci-test
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a lack of permissions in the gitlab Service Account. You have to grant the [proper Role](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/iam/roles#additional-configuration) to deploy Cloud Functions.

You can grant The role: `cloudfunctions.developer` to the Service Account:

> Can create, update, and delete functions.
> Can't set Cloud IAM policies but can view source code.
> Requires [additional configuration](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/iam/roles#additional-configuration) in order to deploy functions.

`Additional configuration:`

> In order to assign a user the Cloud Functions Admin (`roles/cloudfunctions.admin`) or Cloud Functions Developer role (`roles/cloudfunctions.developer`) or a custom role that can deploy functions, you must also assign the user the Service Account User Cloud IAM role (`roles/iam.serviceAccountUser`) on the Cloud Functions Runtime service account.

```
gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding \
  PROJECT_ID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com \
  --member MEMBER \
  --role roles/iam.serviceAccountUser
```

Comment: Glad to read it! Could you please accept this answer? In this way other members can get benefit of it.